# Subprocess calls, are they done in parallel?

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I've been Googling for an answer to this question but nowhere seems to have one. Can anyone tell me if the `subprocess` module does its calls in parallel? The Python docs suggest it can be used to spawn new processes, but it doesn't mention if they are in parallel or not. If they can be done in parallel could you kindly show me an example or link me to one?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It depends on how you use `subprocess`:

```
subprocess.call("some-program")
```

will block until `some-program` completes.

```
p = subprocess.Popen("some-program")
```

will run `some-program` in a separate process, in parallel with the remainder of your script.

Note that the first is simply a convenient wrapper that is equivalent to

```
subprocess.Popen("some-program").wait()
```

`output = subprocess.check_output("some-program")` is basically the same as

```
output, stderr = subprocess.Popen("some-program").communicate()
```

Comment: Arrr ok im using `subprocess.check_output("some-command")` is it possible to just switch to `Popen` from check_output?

Comment: @iNoob, and here we see a demonstration of why specific questions are good! :) You should probably update your question to state this

Comment: @wnnmaw sorry im having a moment, what do you mean update it? Happy to do so but can you elaborate?

Comment: @iNoob, its all good, its a Friday.  You can update your original question by pressing the "edit" button below the the tags

Comment: @wnnmaw lol i was referring to what would you like me to updated it too. ps. its Thurs here ^_^, why am i smiling its a bad thing :(

Comment: @iNoob, ahh, I meant that you should update to include what ```subprocess``` method you were using, but since you got the answer you're looking for it's moot

Comment: Arr lol soz ull have to excuse me im a little special, not [sheldon](http://the-big-bang-theory.com/characters.Sheldon/) special but [Grug Crood](http://dreamworks.wikia.com/wiki/Category:The_Croods_Characters) special

Comment: @wnnmaw What about if you use `suborocess.run` I can't seem to find any documentation. Does it await for the subprocess to finish?

Comment: @VahagnTumanyan, [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) was released with Python 3.5, that came out a year and a half after this answer. It does appear that `subprocess.run` blocks similar to `subprocess.call`