# How to run Ansible as synchronization way?

Tags: ansible

I run a python script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess,time

command = "ansible all -i /etc/ansible/hosts -m shell -a 'echo $(date)>>/tmp/111.txt && sleep 10 && echo $(date)>>/tmp/111.txt'"
subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
time.sleep(10)
print ("OK,DONE!")
```

This is a very sample script,just run a ansible and wait 10 seconds,that should take 20 seconds,but i found the result is only 10 seconds when i finish this script.

Why? How could i fix it? 
by the way,my ansible is 2.5.4.

Comment: Why do you need a script to run ansible ? The commands are pretty straight forward to run. In case you don't want to run the long command you can write a simple shell script that will execute for you ?

Answer (score 0):

You are running your ansible command asynchronously. See this answer here which shows how to use subprocess in a synchronous way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22698825/4276009